# Backbone: How do I put a collection inside a view

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I see many tutorials which don't follow the supposedly best practice of making a model, a view and collection for that model **then** a view for the collection. Which would be the parent view?

How do I make a view for a collection? Also, is it possible for it to keep track of when a model is added or deleted for it to update/re-render?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must do something like this in your collection view:

```
var view = Backbone.View.extend({});
var myView = new view({'collection' : new collection});
```

To handle add/remove event, use this in your initialize function:

```
this.collection.on("add", this.onAdd, this);   
this.collection.on("remove", this.onRemove, this);
```

and in your model view:

```
this.model.on("change", this.onUpdate,this);
```

See it here: http://www.neiker.com.ar/backbone/

(Sorry, I don't speak english)

EDIT: Just use marionette:
https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/blob/master/docs/marionette.collectionview.md

Comment: That clears up a lot. Is there a github for the project you posted?

Comment: I'm glad you find it useful. Not is a project, it's just a test for a new job.